# How to fix ‘gradle project sync failed basic functionality will not work properly’ error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

this is my Bulid.gradle

"logs" [

```
    {
        "outputFile" "D:\\project\\HealthyLife\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-lv\\values-lv.xml",
        "map"[
            {
                "source" "C:\\Users\\mustafa saleem\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-1\\files-1.1\\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\\3feff54b6487cbe05b10a566b3ca1591\\res\\values-lv\\values-lv.xml",
                "from" {
                    "startLines""2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19"
                    "startColumns""4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4"
                    "startOffsets" "105,225,333,442,528,632,754,836,918,1003,1112,1224,1323,1434,1543,1648,1822,1921"
                    "endColumns" "119,107,108,85,103,121,81,81,84,108,111,98,110,108,104,173,98,81"
                    "endOffsets""220,328,437,523,627,749,831,913,998,1107,1219,1318,1429,1538,1643,1817,1916,1998"
                },
                "to": {
                    "startLines" "2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,37",
                    "startColumns": "4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4",
                    "startOffsets": "105,225,333,442,528,632,754,836,918,1003,1112,1224,1323,1434,1543,1648,1822,4714",
                    "endColumns": "119,107,108,85,103,121,81,81,84,108,111,98,110,108,104,173,98,81"}}]}]
```

this is Error:(4, 0) No signature of method: java.lang.String.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (build_b5jvjt9i1oac5ql84p80uvhqa$_run_closure1) values: [build_b5jvjt9i1oac5ql84p80uvhqa$_run_closure1@4e132716]
Possible solutions: getAt(groovy.lang.IntRange), getAt(groovy.lang.Range), getAt(groovy.lang.EmptyRange), getAt(groovy.lang.Range), getAt(groovy.lang.IntRange), getAt(java.lang.String)
Open File[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRIkN.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Try this: 'File' > 'Invalidate Caches / Restart' and then click the 'Invalidate and Restart' button'

It will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks bro,i did what u said but it's still same problem

Comment: have you alredy tried to clear and rebuild the project?